# JMeter - Can I run multiple scenarios in 1 thread group with throughput controllers?

Tags: jmeter

We have 6 user scenarios that we are trying to test on our application concurrently. We are constantly tuning the percentage of threads going to each scenario and total number of threads. In order to make these changes quickly, I've put all the scenarios under 1 thread group and in that thread group I have 6 throughput controllers setup that that total up to 100% with 'per user' unchecked, each scenarios samplers (with thinktimes) are then inside these throughput controllers.

As far as I can tell, this is accomplishing the goal and I see the proper user distribution going through our system but I'm not sure if I should be breaking these out into 6 different thread groups instead. If so, how should I be controlling the percentage of threads going to each scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a good one. It will do what you expect.